# Multiple group in single query of MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've a set of multiple records with different "label" and "purpose"

```
{
    billNumber: "",
    _id: "5c94fbc222ac2a0017e70859",
    label: "5c94fb7722ac2a0017e70857",
    purpose: "Purchasing",
    date: "2019-03-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    amount: 200000
},
{
    billNumber: "",
    _id: "5c95e300a634360017498c39",
    label: "5c94fba222ac2a0017e70858",
    purpose: "Deposit",
    date: "2018-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    amount: 792
}
```

I want to group my records first with "label" id and then with "purpose" and show the result like:

```
[
    {
        "label" : "5c94fb7722ac2a0017e70857",
        "balance" : {
            "purchasing" : 240404,
            "deposit" : 4342
        }
    },
    {
        "label" : "5c94fb7722ac2rewt17e7084w58",
        "balance" : {
            "Purchasing" : 455356,
            "Deposit" : 56577
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: And your issue is?

Comment: What code have you written till now?

Comment: {
            $group : {
               "_id" : {
                  "label" : "$label",
                  "purpose" : "$purpose",
                  "amount" : "$amount"
               },
            }
         },
         {
            $group : { 
               "_id" : "$_id.purpose", 
               "amount" : { $sum : "$_id.amount" } 
            }
         }

Answer (score -1):

In the past I have used the `groupBy` lodash func for this. See: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy

So build a collection of your records, in array of objects:

```
const records = [{
    billNumber: "",
    _id: "5c94fbc222ac2a0017e70859",
    label: "5c94fb7722ac2a0017e70857",
    purpose: "Purchasing",
    date: "2019-03-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    amount: 200000
},
{
    billNumber: "",
    _id: "5c95e300a634360017498c39",
    label: "5c94fba222ac2a0017e70858",
    purpose: "Deposit",
    date: "2018-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    amount: 792
}]
```

Then invoke the Lodash method `groupBy` as `_.groupBy(records, 'label');` which will return:

```
$: { 5c94fb7722ac2a0017e70857: 
   [ { billNumber: '',
       _id: '5c94fbc222ac2a0017e70859',
       label: '5c94fb7722ac2a0017e70857',
       purpose: 'Purchasing',
       date: '2019-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
       amount: 200000 } ],
  5c94fba222ac2a0017e70858: 
   [ { billNumber: '',
       _id: '5c95e300a634360017498c39',
       label: '5c94fba222ac2a0017e70858',
       purpose: 'Deposit',
       date: '2018-05-08T00:00:00.000Z',
       amount: 792 } ] }
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
const records = [{
    billNumber: "",
    _id: "5c94fbc222ac2a0017e70859",
    label: "5c94fb7722ac2a0017e70857",
    purpose: "Purchasing",
    date: "2019-03-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    amount: 200000
},
{
    billNumber: "",
    _id: "5c95e300a634360017498c39",
    label: "5c94fba222ac2a0017e70858",
    purpose: "Deposit",
    date: "2018-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    amount: 792
}]

const grouped = _.groupBy(records, 'label');

console.log(grouped)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```